# If else mongoose find query - no results

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm developing a node.js/express/passport application which uses Mongoose for DB calls.

I am currently trying to check whether there are any results on the query, however regardless of what I try it is still saying there's results - even when there's not!

My code:

```
   User.find({'callsign' : new RegExp('^'+search+'$', "i")}, function(err, callsign){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('No user found'+err);
        req.flash('message','Sorry, something went wrong. Try again.');
        res.render('callSearchResults'),{
            message: req.flash('message'), 
            title: 'Sorry, no results'
        }
    }
    if(callsign){
        console.log('Callsign:'+callsign);
        res.render('callSearchResults',{
            call: callsign,
            title: 'You searched for '+search,
            query: search
        });
    }else{
        console.log('No entries found'+search);
    }
});
```

I have tried using the following to check if the result set is empty, but it always ignores it any carries on.

```
if(callsign==[]){
    console.log("No results");  // Doesn't output anything in console
}

if(callsign==null){
    console.log("No results");  // Doesn't output anything in console
}

if(!callsign.length){
    console.log("No results");  // Doesn't output anything in console
}
```

Yet, the console reads:

```
Callsign:
POST /search 200 902ms - 1.51kb
```

Comment: What does `console.log(callsign)` show?

Answer (score 0):

If you search and there are no results, callsign will be an empty array. Check that by testing (callsign.length === 0). If it returns true then there are no results.

```
if(err){
  //handle error in mongo
}
if(callsign.length === 0){
  //handle search with no reults
}
else {
  //handle search with results
}
```